# Installing a 1/2 above ground pool

Tags: pool, cement

I had to remove a pool because the wall rotted and split. It was a 4x12 and 18 inches in the ground. I want to put it on a cement base.

There already is a sand base there since the old pool was on that.  Advice on the best way to handle this next pool install?  Will I need gravel then re-bar?  And I will pick some kind of padding to go over the cement.

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what you're asking. Are you wondering whether sand is a suitable base for a pool slab? How deep is the sand? What's under it? Please revise your post to be more specific, including your title.

Comment: Why do you want a cement base? Aesthetics? "Robustness"? What kind of pool will it be? Brick & tile? Hard panel? Soft liner? What are you doing about the static soil pressure on the bottom half of the wall?

Comment: It sounds like an above ground pool with a wood wall ; " wall rotted", is that the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the sand and pour directly on it.
Wet the sand down good prior to the pour.
If you do not wet the sand as you dump loads of concrete dry sand will be picked up more not a good thing.

I find welded wire mesh the best for thinner slabs, we used to mix bales of zonolite in our pool bottom and side wall mix I don’t remember the ratio but it worked well with welded wire, we installed a bunch of pools with liners this way years ago back then it was not considered permanent but I believe they changed the law if you still have the above ground temporary part the bottom being concrete won’t change the tax status.

But you can pour over wet sand, and you might have better luck with welded wire reenforcement over rebar.